# Does SDE.ST_LENGTH() calculate the true length of arcs?

Tags: geometry, oracle-dbms, length, st-geometry, true-curves

*Oracle 18c/10.7.1 EGDB*

I have a polyline FC that has features with arcs.

Does the Oracle SDE.ST_LENGTH() function calculate the **true length** of arcs?

Or does it only calculate the straight-line length between the arc's vertices?

Answer (score 0):

I manually measured the length of the line with arcs via the ArcMap measuring tool. The measured length roughly matched the results I get when I query the length using SDE.ST_GEOMETRY(). So that made me think, yes, the true length of the arc gets calculated.

But upon further investigation, it looks like ST_GEOMETRY densifies the arc into many individual vertices:

- [Why does SDE.ST_NUMPOINTS() add extra vertices for lines with arcs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385928/why-does-sde-st-numpoints-add-extra-vertices-for-lines-with-arcs)

So the answer seems to be:

Yes, it calculates the length along the arc quite accurately via densification. **But it doesn't actually calculate the length of the arc**; it only calculates the length between densified vertices.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A comment from @Vince from a [related post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/386183/135445):

> There is one quirky part...the area and perimeter reported on certain shapes which were
> created by perfect functions (e.g., [`SE_shape_generate_circle`](https://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/sdk/arcsde/api/capi/geometry/shapegeneratecircle.htm)) report
> the exact value, not the area/perimeter of the segmented
> approximation). It appears this is applied to CAD curves as well, so
> while the vertex count is from the approximation, the length isn't
> (or, at least, isn't always).