# What densification method does SDE.ST_Geometry use to approximate arcs as segments?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, st-geometry, true-curves, densify

*Oracle 18c; ArcGIS 10.7.1*

---

I have an SDE.ST_Geometry polyline FC that has arcs.

In a [related post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385928/why-does-sde-st-numpoints-add-extra-vertices-for-lines-with-arcs/386183#386183), we established that  true arcs/curves are only available to ArcObjects, whereas the actual geometry contains **approximated segments** of the arcs.

Only those approximated segments are available to SDE.ST_Geometry functions (not the arcs).

**Question:**

What densification method does SDE.ST_Geometry use to approximate  arcs as linear segments?

- Distance
- Angle
- Offset
- Other?

Answer (score 2):

**Densify GP (a related operation):**

We can refer to the [Densify geoprocessing tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/tools/editing-toolbox/densify.htm) which appears to perform a **similar** operation to the *segment approximation* that  SDE.ST_Geometry does.

[image]

> Curve segments are simplified through densification by either the
> **Distance** , **Maximum Deflection Angle**, or  **Maximum Offset Deviation parameter**.
>
> Densification is done segment by segment.
>
> When densifying by **Maximum Offset Deviation**, if the input geometry
> contains circular arcs, then an upper limit on the offset will be
> enforced such that the angle between two consecutive line segments in
> the output cannot exceed ten degrees. This angle can be exceeded if
> you densify by the **Maximum Deflection Angle**.

---

**Use Densify on an Arc:**

As a test, we can use the Densify GP tool to densify a polyline that is an arc (in this case, the polyline is a circle).

The Densify operation works as expected — using the **angle** densification method with 10 degrees.

[image]

[image]

---

**SDE.ST_Geometry:**

So the question is, does SDE.ST_Geometry do something similar to the Densify GP tool?

1. Get the vertices of the SDE.ST_Geometry feature:

> ```
> create or replace view a_test_vw as (
> select
>     cast(rownum as number(38,0)) as objectid,
>     n.num as vertex,
>     sde.st_x(sde.st_pointn(shape,n.num)) as x,
>     sde.st_y(sde.st_pointn(shape,n.num)) as y
> from
>     a_test_fc
> cross join
>     numbers n
> where
>     n.num <= sde.st_numpoints(shape)
> )
> ```

2. Add the vertices/query to the map:

[image]

3. We can see that SDE.ST_Geometry created 36+1 vertices, just like Densify did.

- The points are exactly the same: `360 degrees / 36 vertices = 10 degrees`

[image]

---

**Answer:**

As far as I can tell, SDE.ST_Geometry densifies arcs using the 10 degree angle method.